# VBA Looping Through Multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on building code which can loop through a column (B5:B) on multiple worksheets to find matching values. If the Value on one worksheet's column (B5:B) is equal to a worksheet name, then the worksheet name is placed on the adjacent column (C5:C) to where the value was found. I am not a programmer, but I've been learning VBA to make this happen. So far I have tried unsuccessfully to use the For Next Loop (starting with the 3rd sheet), the For Each ws in Thisworkbook.sheets method. But I don't seem to be able to make it work. I've searched all over the internet for something similar, but no dice. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub MatchingPeople()
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim g As Long
    Dim w As Long

    i = Sheets("Anthony").Name
    g = Sheets("Anthony").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For w = 3 To Sheets.Count
        lastrow = Sheets(w).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Set NewRang = Sheets("Anthony").Cells(g + 1, 3)
        On Error Resume Next
        With Sheets(w).Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(lasty, 2))
            Set c = .Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstaddress = c.Address
                Do
                    NewRang.Value = Sheets(w).Name
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress
            End If
        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Max, I hope you don't mind I indented your code. You should look to indent this way in the future because it makes it much easier for you (and us!) to read your code and to spot some simple errors quickly.

Comment: Here's something to start with: I'm seeing lots of variables which haven't been defined. `NewRang`, `firstaddress` and also `lasty` which isn't declared or given a value before you use it here: `Cells(lasty,2)`

Comment: Commenting out `On Error Resume Next` and stepping through code may find something.

Comment: No I definitely don't mind you indenting the code, I've started doing it after your comment. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 versions, one using the Find method like in your code, the other using a For loop

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MatchingPeopleFind()
    Dim i As Long, lrColB As Long
    Dim wsCount As Long, wsName As String
    Dim found As Variant, foundAdr As String

    wsCount = Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount >= 3 Then
        For i = 3 To wsCount
            With Worksheets(i)
                wsName = .Name
                lrColB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                With .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(lrColB, 2))
                    Set found = .Find(wsName, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If Not found Is Nothing Then
                        foundAdr = found.Address
                        Do
                            found.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = wsName
                            Set found = .FindNext(found)
                        Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> foundAdr
                    End If
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub MatchingPeopleForLoop()
    Dim wsCount As Long, wsName As String, i As Long, j As Long

    wsCount = Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount >= 3 Then
        For i = 3 To wsCount
            With Worksheets(i)
                wsName = .Name
                For j = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    If .Cells(j, 2).Value2 = wsName Then .Cells(j, 3).Value2 = wsName
                Next
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub Bygone()

Dim x As Long

Dim y As Long

Dim z As Long

Dim w As Long

Dim a As Long

Dim b As Long

Dim c As Long

Dim m As Long

a = Sheets.Count

```
For m = 3 To a

   x = Sheets(m).Cells(3, 3).Value

       For b = 3 To a

            w = Sheets(b).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

                For z = 5 To w

                    y = Sheets(b).Cells(z, 1)

                        Select Case x

                            Case y
                              c =Sheets(m).Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
                              Sheets(m).Cells(c, 3).Value = Sheets(b).Name
                         End Select
                Next z

      Next b
Next m
```

End Sub